# How to use JSON_TABLE in Oracle 11g

Tags: json, oracle, oracle11g

The below select statement works fine with Oracle 12c or higher.

```
SELECT J.*
  FROM JSON_TABLE('{BookId:1001, BookName:"Harry Porter"}', '$'
 COLUMNS (  BOOKID  NUMBER   PATH '$.BookId',
            BOOKNAME  VARCHAR2   PATH '$.BookName')) J;
```

Is there any way to make it working for Oracle 11g?

Comment: is apex_json package installed on your system?

Comment: No. Will apex_json resolve this issue? If yes, please share the link.

Comment: you can use `apex_json.to_xmltype`. [Refer](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/tips-for-parsing-json-in-apex) .

Answer (score 0):

No. JSON_TABLE was introduced for the first time in Oracle 12.1.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/an-introduction-to-json-support-in-the-oracle-database#json-support-in-12c

There are a couple of open-source methods of handling JSON in 11g. See here for comments and links: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9529416000346458881